# Set rootViewController of UINavigationController by method other than initWithRootViewController

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitoolbar, iphone-5

How Do I set the `rootViewController` of `UINavigationController` by a method other than `initWithRootViewController`?

I want use `initWithNavigationBarClass:toolbarClass:` to deliver a custom toolbar for my NavigationController, so I don't think I can use `initWithRootViewController`.

Comment: One approach I've just discovered is: [navigationController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObject:(Pointer to View Controller that should be the root view controller)]]; is this the best way? I assume you should only call this in the AppDelegate file at the didFinishLaunching delegate method, as it seems risky messing with UINavigationController's view controller array after this

Answer (score 168, accepted):

You can solve this by calling `setViewControllers`.

Like this:

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithNavigationBarClass:[MyNavigationBar class] toolbarClass:[UIToolbar class]];

[navigationController setViewControllers:@[yourRootViewController] animated:NO];
```

Swift version:

```
let navigationController = UINavigationController(navigationBarClass: MyNavigationBar.self, toolbarClass: UIToolbar.self)

navigationController.setViewControllers([yourRootViewController], animated: false)
```

Comment: Thanks for confirming. This might need to go in a separate question but I assume the initWithNav.. means that all my toolbars will have the same appearance I set in the custom subclass. How do I then have different styled toolbars for different sections of my app? Do I return different toolbars from that custom subclass? Or is there a better approach?

Comment: For that you can use `navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];` or however  you want to style it in the `-(void)viewDidAppear:animated:` methods of your ViewControllers

Comment: So this would override the fact that in my UIToolBar subclass I'm overriding drawRect and setting a custom background? This is how I implement this: UIImage *backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"UIToolBar_Background.png"];
    [backgroundImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];

Comment: I'm not sure if it overrides as much as a `drawRect` customization, but its the default method for overriding the `UIToolbar` properties of a `UINavigationController`.

Comment: Any idea on this follow up question I posted on an issue I'm encountering. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16215981/when-subclassing-uitoolbar-to-have-a-custom-background-the-bottom-half-of-toolba

Answer (score 30):

**Knowledge Sharing Using Swift:**

Changing root view controller from class other than app delegate.swift

```
let appdelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
var homeViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("HomeViewController") as! HomeViewController
let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: homeViewController)
appdelegate.window!.rootViewController = nav
```

Hope this will helpful for someone.

Changing rootviewcontroller With Animation can be achieved with:

```
UIView.transitionWithView(self.window!, duration: 0.5, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionFlipFromLeft, animations: {
    self.window?.rootViewController = anyViewController
}, completion: nil)
```

We can write a generalised method too, similar to [this.](https://gist.github.com/nvkiet/6368d1d45c4ea3e6d9cb)

Comment: hi @Arvind, can you tell me the best place to put this code? Should it be at the top of AppDelegate.swift so that the variables are globally available? Or perhaps it needs to be within a class somewhere since it's instantiating views? thanks

Comment: Yes, you can use at func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool.  Other than you can on any view controller. as you may required when you ask for logout.

Comment: @Arvind how to deal with animation? No animation is shown and the rootView is shown instantly.

Comment: @Engnyl: I have update the answer. Thanks for your query, that make it more updated.

Comment: getting nil on self.navigationController

Comment: This question is "Set rootViewController of UINavigationController by method other than initWithRootViewController" and your answer to use initWithRootViewController? Why?

Comment: This answer changes the root view controller of the entire window though. The question spefically asks to set the root view controller of a single navigationcontroller.

Answer (score 17):

this one works for me, hope it helps you,

```
let rootVC:LoginViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginViewController") as! LoginViewController
let nvc:UINavigationController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("RootNavigationController") as! UINavigationController
nvc.viewControllers = [rootVC]
UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController = nvc
```

Comment: you saved my day!

Comment: getting nil on self.navigationController

Comment: @WasimAhmed that mean you are not having navigation controller as root view controller

Answer (score 2):

In swift 3.0 xcode8.1

in general settings delete in Main Interface: Main <-this
after  Main Interface:

```
class AppDelegate...

 var window: UIWindow?

    fun application...

      window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
      window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
      window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: NewYourController)
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. You're calling initWithRootViewController, exactly what the question is asking how to avoid.

Answer (score -3):

```
  let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)         
  let yourNewRootView = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("yourNewRootView") as? yourNewRootView


   self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)

    UIView.transitionWithView(self.window!, duration: 0.1, options: [UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionFlipFromRight,UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionFlipFromLeft], animations: 
    {
        // animation

        }, completion: { (finished: Bool) -> () in

            self.window?.rootViewController = nil
            self.window?.rootViewController = yourNewRootView
            self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    })
```