# When subclassing UIToolBar to have a custom background the bottom half of toolbar is black?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitoolbar

I'm subclassing UIToolBar, here is how I override the `drawRect` method of UIToolBar:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    UIImage *backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"UIToolBar_Background.png"];
    [backgroundImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
}
```

The app uses a UINavigationController paradigm initialized with `initWithNavigationBarClass` method.

The issue is that the bottom half of toolbar is black? The UIToolBar_Background.png is 44 pixels height (or 88 for retina). It should not have it's bottom half black.

Answer (score 0):

By subclassing UIToolBar and overriding drawRect, you eliminate some of UIToolBar's own drawing. Why not use the appearance api to set a background image:

```
[[UIToolbar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"UIToolBar_Background.png"]
                        forToolbarPosition:UIToolbarPositionBottom
                                barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

alternatively, you could use the subclassing route, just make sure you call [super drawrect:rect] before doing your own drawing:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [super drawRect:rect];
    UIImage *backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"UIToolBar_Background.png"];
    [backgroundImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
}
```

Comment: Thanks Marcel for response, key reason is I need to have an oversized button in the middle of my toolbar. Something like shown on these tutorials. http://idevrecipes.com/2010/12/16/raised-center-tab-bar-button/ Right now I've been adding a toolbar as a view on the viewController but I'm struggling with getting it to be correct Y position all the time esp. with 4inch display. So I'm trying to encapsulate everything in a UIToolbar.

Comment: I aded the [super drawRect:rect]; still getting half the toolbar cut off. Is it something to do with default tintColour or barStyle?

Comment: The .png has a alpha transparency on the bottom half. This I believe is what is causing the issue.

Comment: **The issue was caused by the .png (UIToolBar_Background.png) having an alpha transparency.** 

 - Specifically the bottom half of the image had transparency, hence the bottom half being black.
 - This leads me to believe that the drawInRect method that I was calling on the UIImage instance is not capable of rendering transparency. It's beyond my current knowledge to describe why this is. 
 - I could use the above code with an image, a .png, without transparency and the whole image was displayed. I'll move this comment to the answer when I'm allowed

Comment: your code for the appearance API seems to crash my app, I had to use:  [[UIToolbar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"UIToolBar_Background.png"] forToolbarPosition:UIToolbarPositionBottom barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];